# issues to change the height and width of swf in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hai am trying to add the height and width of swf dynamically but i cannot change `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight` and also am tring with another method also.

```
 [SWF( width="900", height="400")]
```

Its working fine but while adding the value dynamically it cannot change.

```
var hei:Number=500;
var wid:Number=300;
[SWF( width=wid, height=hei)]
```

Comment: What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
[SWF( width="900", height="400")]
```

is like telling the compiler to set properties for the SWF.

The variables you have written come into play only at runtime during which the compiler has no role to play. So basically, your code will be ignored.

You might want to have a look at this discussion [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-335606.html).

Comment: How to resize?kindly guide me

Comment: You cannot set the SWF size at runtime.

Comment: Why?then how to change swf size dynamically?

Comment: You can't. You can compile the SWF in ONE size only. You can scale it in html page though.